# I can't declare a class object with arrays in the parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, class

i'm new to programming.
I'm trying to make a class who start with :

```
public class Team {

    String teamName;
    String [] player= new String[4];
    Competition [] competitions=new Competition[2];

    public Team (String newTeamnName, String [] newPlayer, Competition [] newCompetition) {
        teamName= newTeamnName;
        player= newPlayer;
        competitions=newCompetition;
    }
```

but when using the constructor whith this:

```
public class TeamDemo {

    public static void main (String [] arg){
        Team marc=new ("marcTeam",{"marcello","dfsf","sdfsd"},{"comp1","comp2"})
}
```

I get an error message about the `array {"marcello","dfsf","sdfsd"}` and `{"comp1","comp2"}` that array initializer is not allowed here.

I can't declare a class object with arrays in the parameter ?

Comment: Team marc=new Team("marcTeam",{"marcello","dfsf","sdfsd"},{"comp1","comp2"});

Comment: I don't understand the answer's, can someone explain, it's the first time i use array

Comment: i try the vararg , but it say it have to be the las, but i have 2 array, so it doewsn't work, the rest of the answer i don't understand

Comment: 1. In your main you have to write "new Team" since the compiler needs to know what object you are creating. 2. your last argument {'"comp1", "comp2"} is an array of strings. But you wrote in your constructor that you expect an array of Competition. so you would have something like 'new Team("markTeam", {"marcello", "dfsf", "sdfsd"}, {new Competition(?), new Competition(?)});' i dont know your competition-constructor thats why ?.

Comment: The answers there say, that `{...}` can only be used why declaring an array variable. You don't do that in your code, so you have to use the general way `new String[]{....}`. And before you wonder `new String[]{"comp1","comp2"}` won't work here, because your code expects `Competition[]`, not `String[]`, so you need to create `Competition` instances instead of using String literals.